# Gitlab relative URL under apache proxy pass

Tags: apache, gitlab, proxypass

I am running gitlab inside a docker which is mapped to port 8880 on my localhost. So I can access it using the URL 

**http://localhost:8880**

But I have used apache proxy pass to create following mapping
   
 **localhost:8880 ------> localhost/gitlab**

So that my users can access gitlab through **localhost/gitlab**. Everything seems to be working fine but the problem arises when the page is rendered. All the link in the page generated by Gitlab uses relative url like

/assets/favicon-baaa14bade1248aa6165e9d34e7d83c0.ico

/assets/application-296ff8a0c87574e522a2911224b5350b.css

/assets/print-1df3ea9b8ff148a6745321899e0cb213.css

This causes apache to redirect them to **localhost/assets/...** when clicked. Which results in 404 Error which is obvious as the resource path is incorrect. The link should have been generated as **localhost/gitlab/assets/....** so that apache can map them correctly to **localhost/gitlab/assets/...**

I have tried using the Apache rewrite module, Nginx rewrite module but none of them worked. Is there anyway I can change the relative URL generated by gitlab?

Comment: You might check out the `mod_proxy_html` module to fix this. Specifically, the [`ProxyHTMLURLMap`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html#proxyhtmlurlmap) directive, which can rewrite the URLs in the served HTML pages to point to the correct location. You can use `mod_proxy` to rewrite cookies as well, which might be necessary to fix authentication tokens. A better solution might be to serve gitlab on its own host (e.g. `gitlab.localhost`) instead of a subdirectory, so that minimal modification of the traffic would be needed when proxying to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this feature is not currently supported in gitlab. If you must use a relative url, consider using omnibus gitlab as it has support for relative urls.

When you send a request to localhost/gitlab, the apache server faithful forwards it to localhost:8880. But neither gitlab nor nginx know it is coming from a relative url, only apache does. This becomes a problem since the resource paths in gitlab are constructed with the fqdn - localhost:8880. And apache only modifies the header of the request to localhost/gitlab not the links and resources embedded in the request.

Comment: But I don't like this answer!  *whine*

Comment: Old post, but in case anyone stumbles across it like I did, The omnibus distribution of gitlab **does not support relative URL** installation: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/182